# Angular2 local template variables

Tags: angular

In the following example, I designate a local variable `#input` to multiple radio buttons. When clicking the `<tr>` I want to select the radio button inside.

And the following code works fine, but I don't understand why.

How can Angular2 "know" which input I'm refering to when ALL of them have the local variable`#input`?

HTML

```
  <tr *ngFor="let office of employee.offices" (click)="selectOffice(input)">
    <td class="select-office-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="office" #input />
    </td>
    <td>
      {{office.officeName}}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

JS

```
selectOffice(input) {
   input.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the JS be selectOffice(user) as opposed to selectUser(input)?

Comment: and I believe it's because each office has it's own mini-template and is unaware of the other mini-templates that have been created by the *ngFor which means that only one is triggered

Comment: updated. ok thanks for the info, do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bhushan said, `ngFor` is a structural directive so it's a shortcut for a template-based structure. In short, it can be desugared into the following in your template:

```
<template ngFor let-office [ngForOf]="employee.offices">
  <tr (click)="selectOffice(input)">
    (...)
  </tr>
</template>
```

The way to define local variable for templates is the following:

- Add the prefix `let-`. For example, `let-office` will define a variable `office`.
- If you don't define a value, the value of the `$implicit` entry in the template context will be used. In the case of ngFor, it's the current element in the iteration. Here: `let-office`.
- You can also specify a value. For example, if you want to define a variable for the index in the loop: `let-i="index"`. In the case, the variable `i` will contain the corresponding value.

Regarding variables define with the `#` prefix. They correspond to a DOM element if the element they apply on isn't a component. If it's a component, it corresponds to the component. For example, `input` in `<input #input/>` corresponds to an `ElementRef` and the DOM element can be accessed through its `nativeElement` property.

You can also specify a value for such variables. In this case, you can select a specific directive applied on the element. For example `<input #ctrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="val"/>`. The value corresponds to what is specified within the `exportAs` attribute in the directive declaration:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'child-dir',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
class ChildDir {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `<child-dir #c="child"></child-dir>`,
  directives: [ChildDir]
})
class MainComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *ngFor is a structural directive i.e. it modifies the DOM.

thus, for each record its creating its creating separate `input element`.

Also you are declaring `#input` as a local variable for `input element` thus `#input` refers to each input element separately.

if you want to access the value entered in text input,
you can do following:

```
selectOffice(input.value)
```

because #input refers to html input element.

for more info, you can refer to :

[Displaying Data using structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html)