# What is the "let-" attribute in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

In the `ng-bootstrap` [modal documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) there are uses of some kind of `let-*` attribute that seemed to be used to link a function or event for later use.  If you look at the `(click)` events and the `let-c` / `let-d` attributes at the top of the examples, you can get a feel for what it does.  This appears to be a feature of Angular and has nothing to do with `ng-bootstrap`.

But what is this called?  What does it do?  Where are the Angular docs for this feature?

Here's an example of what I'm referring to.  See the very first line.

```js
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- content here omitted -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I've Googled this to no avail; the only results I get are about the `let` keyword when using `ngFor`, which is obviously not related.

Comment: look at  https://gist.github.com/mhevery/d3530294cff2e4a1b3fe15ff75d08855    and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264694/angular2-local-template-variables

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `let-*` attribute is a feature of the `ng-template` to inject a variable into the template by sourcing the variable's value from the context.

```html
<ng-template #example let-title="fooBar">
     <span>{{title}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

In the above example the template variable `title` exists because there is `let-title` and it's value will be equal to the property `fooBar` from the context object.

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="example; context: {fooBar:'This is the value'}"></ng-container>
```

The above inserts the template reference `#example` and passes it the `context`.

There are multiple ways to use a template but the `let-*` is the **only** way to inject template variables.

Reference for NgComponent:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Reference to the `let` microsyntax:

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax

A nice blog on the topic:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

It's difficult to find information about `let` because it's part of the Angular *microsyntax* parser. Which is used by both templates and `*ngFor`.

Maybe you've seen this before in Angular.

```html
<div ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index">....</div>
```

The above is the same as writing.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">....</div>
```

So there are **two** ways to write a `let-*` assignment in Angular. This is what they call the *microsyntax* parser. You can actually write your own directives that use this special syntax, but you have to look at the source of Angular to figure it out.

Comment: Wow, interesting.  Thank you.  Any chance you could please include a link to the appropriate Angular docs?  I always appreciate it when my users RTFM, so I try to take my own advice when possible :)

Comment: let- only works with loops?

Answer (score 1):

Third party angular libraries will sometimes introduce their own support for directives.  Here's one example from primeng:

`<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">`

This will make sense after reading the [primeng docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v10-lts/#/table).